# Creating a 01:00 Countdown Timer (Chronometer) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, chronometer

I implemented a Chronometer object in my Android Application. What is the simple code to create a 01:00 countdown timer, so the user has 1 minute to complete the current level?

Answer (score 0):

does Chronometer take minutes? I seem to recall it taking milliseconds

anyway, just pass it the time to count down from, then at finish, this should be a method that is included, do your command, like popup some kind of alertdialog that blocks the user or finish the activity

Comment: I believe it is milliseconds. I understand everything your telling me, except my problem is I just don't know how to apply it into code without getting millions of errors. Can you help me out with coding it?

I Declared the following:


Chronometer cm;
cm = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.Timer);